# Testflight Alternative for Production

Tags: ios, production, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm sure most of the iOS and Android people know about TestFlight by now.

My Question is, is there any 3rd-party platforms like this that allow you to download a production app?

For example.

Business A has 200 devices, all over the country, running "His App"

Then he decides to release an update for this app.

As the App is an internal one, it isn't on the App Store and doesn't need to go through review, its ready to be downloaded by all 200 devices.

He sends an email to all 200 people, saying "Run the app "Insert Name Here (Testflight alternative)" and click "Update"

This then updates the app on the device via the internet. No Cables or computers.

So pretty much looking for a "ProductionFlight" rather than "TestFlight" does anybody know of such an easy system?

Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of alternatives... The ones I use are http://appblade.com (has a cool 25 device free limit and then one dollar per device which is nice), the other is much more interesting, it's called HockeyKit (not the HockeyApp everyone has heard about) and it's a free, open-source MIT licensed, self hosted app distribution server that works and feels very much like Testflight ( the client install part anyway ) D*mn cool if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

***For iOS***, Aside from the Developer Enterprise program (which would probably be what the business in your example would want to use), you can also distribute to up to 50 'Promo Codes' via iTunes Connect which allows anyone who has one to download the Production version of the app once accepted into the App Store.

The obvious drawback is the limitation of how many promo codes you are allowed to request, but you can receive 50 new promo codes with every "update" of your application — meaning you could potentially have more, but only 50 people would have the 'updated' version, which could be an issue if you actually made critical changes/fixes to your production app and needed *all* existing users to download the new version.

More information can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/12_RequestingPromoCodes/RequestingPromoCodes.html

Answer (score -1):

The iOS Developer Enterprise program is meant for this. With an enterprise account, you do not need to register UDID of devices to deploy application for employees. App can be downloaded directly on the iPad through a link opened in Safari.

The only limitation is that this is accepted only for application distributed to internal employees.

See some more explanation here:
http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/deploy/app-distribution.html